# Oracle SQL Trigger with Conditional Update based on Information in Separate Table

Tags: sql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have two tables:

- `cost_bank` (this is where I want the trigger)
- `master_data` (this table has information I need to check)

I want to build an "after insert" trigger on `cost_bank` which runs when the newly inserted `cost_bank.work_code` is in the `master_data` table with a `master_data.charge_type = 'EX'`. If that scenario is true, I want the trigger to update the newly added row only (can specify by `ID`) in `cost_bank` with the value from `master_data.r_cost_center` for `cost_bank.cost_center`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER expense_charge_cost_center
 AFTER INSERT ON cost_bank FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new.work_code in (select work_code from master_data where charge_type = 'EX'))
BEGIN
   update cost_bank set cost_center = (select r_cost_center
   from master_data where work_code = new.work_code) where id = new.id;
END;
```

Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the same table, you want a *before* insert trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER expense_charge_cost_center
 BEFORE INSERT ON cost_bank FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (new.work_code in (select work_code from master_data where charge_type = 'EX'))
BEGIN
   select r_cost_center into :new.cost_center
   from master_data
   where work_code = new.work_code;
END;
```

Actually, I'm not sure if subqueries work with `when`, so you might need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER expense_charge_cost_center
 BEFORE INSERT ON cost_bank FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   if (new.work_code in (select work_code from master_data where charge_type = 'EX')) then
       select r_cost_center into :new.cost_center
       from master_data
       where work_code = new.work_code;  -- I'm guessing you also want charge_type = 'EX'
   end if;
END;
```